# Custom login vs existing service auth?

Tags: authentication, facebook-login, backend

When needing to setup a login system for your app, both backend and front-end, what is the quickest to implement:

- create your own custom login (username, email, password...)
- use one of the existing credential services (FB, Twitter, Linkedin, G+ etc)

Thanks for your opinions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course using an existing service is faster, especially with Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

"Get code" > done. No database needed, no PHP needed, no need to think about security and stuff because that´s all done by Facebook.